# How should I unit test functions with many subfunctions?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

I'm looking to better understand I should test functions that have many substeps or subfunctions.

Let's say I have the functions

```
// Modify the state of class somehow
public void DoSomething(){
    DoSomethingA();
    DoSomethingB();
    DoSomethingC();
}
```

Every function here is public. Each subfunction has 2 paths. So to test every path for `DoSomething()` I'd have 2*2*2 = 8 tests. By writing 8 tests for `DoSomething()` I will have indirectly tested the subfunctions too.

So should I be testing like this, or instead write unit tests for each of the subfunctions and then only write 1 test case that measures the final state of the class after `DoSomething()` and ignore all the possible paths? A total of 2+2+2+1 = 7 tests. But is it bad then that the `DoSomething()` test case will depend on the other unit test cases to have complete coverage?

Comment: Test each method's outcome. You only need to test that DoSomething calls the other methods because that's all it does.

Comment: @artm I see but does that not make the test less robust then? If I ever decide to modify `DoSomething()` the test will break. But I suppose it will be an easy test to change since it is so simple.

Comment: You should *not* test that DoSomething() calls the other methods *precisely* because a change in how DoSomething() internally works would break its test.  Black box testing FTW.  White-box testing (with mocks etc) is only useful when testing things that do not return results, and therefore by their nature, the only thing testable about them is what they call and how they call it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears to be a very prevalent *religious* belief that testing should be unit testing. While I do not intend to underestimate the usefulness of unit testing, I would like to point out that it is just one possible flavor of testing, and its extensive (or even exclusive) use is indicative of people (or environments) that are somewhat insecure about what they are doing.

In my experience knowledge of the inner workings of a system is useful as a hint for testing, but not as an instrument for testing.  Therefore, black box testing is far more useful in most cases, though that's admittedly in part because I do not happen to be insecure about what I am doing.  (And that is in turn because I use assertions *extensively*, so essentially all of my code is constantly testing itself.)

Without knowing the specifics of your case, I would say that in general, the fact that `DoSomething()` works by invoking `DoSomethingA()` and then `DoSomethingB()` and then `DoSomethingC()` is an implementation detail that your black-box test should best be unaware of.  So, I would definitely ***not*** test that  `DoSomething()` invokes `DoSomethingA()`, `DoSomethingB()`, and `DoSomethingC()`, I would only test to make sure that it returns the right results, and using the knowledge that it does in fact invoke those three functions as a hint I would implement precisely those 7 tests that you were planning to use.

On the other hand, it should be noted that if `DoSomethingA()` and `DoSomethingB()` and `DoSomethingC()` are *also* public functions, then you should *also* test them individually, too.

Comment: Are you familiar with Zed Shaw's 'Learn Python the Hard Way'? In his chp 47, he suggests exercises for automated testing, talking about unittest. His test_ functions do not correspond 1:1 to the methods/functions in the class to be tested. Having read about unittest and integration test (and other tests) I am confused whether Zed practices unittest or something else. I get the idea of his test_ functions as they test the intention behind the methods in the class. But it strikes me that he does not succinctly test argument-return relations. Is that unittest or integration test? Thanks!

Comment: @Johan no, I am not familiar with this book.  (I avoid scripting languages.)  So, I do not know what Zed Shaw does. But if you want to read more about _**my**_ approach to testing, you can read this: https://blog.michael.gr/2022/10/incremental-integration-testing.html or this: https://blog.michael.gr/2021/12/white-box-vs-black-box-testing.html or anything under this label: https://blog.michael.gr/search/label/testing

Comment: I'm reading, and "the unit of isolation is the test, not the unit under test" (cf. the white-black piece) helped me better understand the points of views I've encountered e.g. on SE softwareengineering. Cheers!

Comment: @Johan yes, but as I explain in the "incremental integration testing" post, this is just an unwarranted mental acrobatic. What Ian cooper is doing there is that he is redefining the term "unit testing", which is arbitrary on his behalf. This term already has a specific definition and it is not the one he would like it to have.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely test every subfunction seperately (because they're public).
It would help you find the problem if one pops up.

If DoSomething only uses other functions, I wouldn't bother writing additional tests for it. If it has some other logic, I would test it, but assume all functions inside work properly (if they're in a different class, mock them).

The point is finding what the function does that is not covered in other tests and testing that.

Answer (score 0):

Indirect testing should be avoided. You should write unit tests for each function explicitly. After that You should mock submethods and test your main function. For example :

You have a method which inserts a user to DB and method is like this :

```
void InsertUser(User user){

var exists = SomeExternal.UserExists(user);

if(exists)
throw new Exception("bla bla bla");

//Insert codes here
}
```

If you want to test InsertUser function, you should mock external/sub/nested methods and test behaviour of InsertUser function. 

This example creates two tests: 
1 - "When user exists then Should throw Exception"
 2 - "When user does not exist then Should insert user"