# How to get the return value that a called function gets from other function?

Tags: javascript, sinon

For example, I have two functions:

```
function functionOne() {
    var a = 1;
    var b = 2;
    var sum = a + b;

    return sum;
}

function functionTwo() {
    var receivedSum = functionOne();
    console.log('just do something with ' + receivedSum);
}
```

I want to test functionTwo and need to somehow get the value of receivedSum.
Is it possible? Would Sinon.js or some other libraries help me?

Comment: If you're using Jest or Sinon then you could mock the `functionOne()` to return some known value and ensure that your test works correctly.

Comment: I don't know the return value and want to get it in my test.

Comment: I'm not sure of the purpose. Your function one is always going to return the same result. So if you've already tested that in isolation why do you need to test it again within the scope of functionTwo.

Comment: the example is artificial, the real function one returns different results and my test is integration

Comment: This question is already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30283767/how-should-i-unit-test-functions-with-many-subfunctions

Comment: yes, I understand the point, but I want to know if there is a possibility to somehow get the value of  a "subfunction"

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is black box testing, but it *is* possible to wrap an inner function in a spy and check the value that it returned using [`spy.returnValues`](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v6.3.4/spies/#spyreturnvalues):

lib.js

```js
export const libFunc = () => 'the value';
```

code.js

```js
import { libFunc } from './lib';

export const func = () => {
  // ...do stuff...
  const value = libFunc();
  // ...do more stuff...
}
```

code.test.js

```js
import * as sinon from 'sinon';

import * as lib from './lib';
import { func } from './code';

test('func', () => {
  const spy = sinon.spy(lib, 'libFunc');  // spy on libFunc
  func();  // call func which calls libFunc
  expect(spy.returnValues[0]).toBe('the value');  // SUCCESS
});
```